# Django - How to remove primary_key attribute from field?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, primary-key

So I have a model in my database that I have now realized it doesn't make sense to make the primary key. I would like to remove the primary key attribute from the field and use the default django autofield as a primary key. How can I do this? If I try and just remove the primary_key attribute it creates the new id field but asks for a default. If I try and create a new id = autofield it does the same thing.

Code below...

```
class Textbook(models.Model):
    textbook_name = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    class_name = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    author = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    isbn = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    auto_id = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)

    @property
    def NumWishes(self):
        return self.wishlist_set.count()
    @property
    def NumPosts(self):
        return self.posting_set.count()
    @property
    def DemSup(self):
        if (self.posting_set.count() != 0):
            showmethemoney = float((self.wishlist_set.count()))/(self.posting_set.count())
        else:
            showmethemoney = 0
        return showmethemoney

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('class_name', 'isbn')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.textbook_name
```

Originally isbn was the primary key but I now want to add a unique_together field with class name so I am removing the primary key attribute from isbn. The table is currently empty which should make this easier.

Thanks.

Comment: I doubt you can do that without dropping the table completely.

Comment: So, comment out everything to do with the tables, run psql and drop the tables, uncomment and makemigations?

Comment: Don't think you'd need to comment anything out. Just drop the tables in psql, delete all existing migrations, and makemigrations again.

Comment: Ok thanks, Ill give it a try.

Answer (score -1):

Things I tried before makemigrations and migrate:

-Dropping all tables and clearing migrations with a command (Didn't work for me)

-Dropping all tables and physically going into the migrations folder and deleting everything but **init**.py. (This worked)

Dropping tables in the postgresql database can be completed by running:
DROP TABLE "tablename";

I now have one migration in my application but everything is working fine.